# Get rid of OpenLayers gap between tiles

Tags: css, openlayers, tile

I have a problem with my OpenLayers map,. I can't get the tiles to be one next to the other. I already checked for intrusive CSS but I didn't find anything. Can someone give me a hand on this?

My current code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms",
                {'layers':'bluemarble'}
            );
            map.addLayer(wms);
            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        });
</script>
```

I'll leave a screenshot: [image]

Comment: with that code is nothing wrong, i tried it and for me it works just fine. Is there any extra information you could give us? Are there any errors in the console? Did you at some point change the reference system for the map?

Comment: The only extra information I can give is that I'm using Bootstrap 2.2.1 and Font Awesome. I didn't change anything from OL, that code is directly extracted from a tutorial :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution after searching in Google for "openlayers bootstrap". There seems to be a problem with intrusive CSS from Bootstrap that is being solved at the OpenLayers trunk, but it's not in stable yet.

To solve the problem you just have to add this CSS rule:

```
#map img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

(where #map is your map identifier, could be a class or a div, whatever)

Please check the order in which this CSS loads, because I was trying to load this rule *before* the OpenLayers JS file and it didn't work. It was overwritten by OL. In the end I had to put it directly on the HTML file.